# Windows error reporting - reports service as hang during loading of service dependent windows dll-s

Tags: windows, operating-system, freeze, windows-error-reporting

I have a service that starts at Win7 startup. If I start the service after boot I cannot find any warning in event log reported by Windows Error Reporting service, but if it starts automatically during boot I get this:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: ServiceHang
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: serviceName
P2: serviceName
P3: 0.0.0.0
P4: 10
P5: 2
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 46283ee5-85ba-11e2-9242-001a4d425476
Report Status: 4
```

Looking into the wer generated file is says :

```
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\..\serviceName.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
```

It *seems* like that while loading of the service by the windows loader it was detected something that looks like a hang. But I collected logs using performance recorder during boot for the described report and I could see from that the following:

[image]

It looks that by measuring the distance between loading of the .exe (from the graph above) and the loading of the module that is not mentioned in the WER report (kernel32.dll) is no more than 200 ms (and all these are microsoft dll-s). I wonder why is WER reporting that as a hang and if I I can do something about it. I always reproduces at system boot and not in any other condition.

*NOTE* The service starts successfully. It's only the nagging event viewer report at every boot.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? i would love to hear about it if you did. Thanks.

Comment: The kind of investigation done using the timing for components loading was a red herring(and the fact that in WER it was mentioned some dlls). Service hang was caused by something that took much more time (30s ore more), things that happened long after dll-s loading that could not be seen in our application logs until we added extra logs :-)